# Simple Rails CanCanCan rule producing "association names must be a Symbol"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm using `CanCanCan` for authorisation in my Rails4 project, and have a set of abilities that begins:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    case user.role
      when :administrator
        can :manage, :all
      when :modeller
        can :manage, Model
        can :manage, Scenario
        #can :manage, MarketAssumption
# ... and so on.
```

In a view I have

```
<% if can? :view, Project %>
```

Which works exactly as it should. However, if I uncomment the line:

```
        can :manage, MarketAssumption
```

the view fails on the call to `can?` with "association names must be a Symbol".

`MarketAssumption` is defined in `app\models\market_assumption.rb` with:

```
class MarketAssumption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to Scenario
end
```

in pretty much the same way as `Model` and `Scenario`. The controller begins:

```
class MarketAssumptionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_market_assumption, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

as I think it should.

Where else should I look for whatever makes MarketAssumption differ from `Model` and `Scenario` in a way that `CanCanCan` doesn't like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `belongs_to Scenario` line. You've given that as a class name, not a symbol. Change it to `belongs_to :scenario` and your code should work fine. I expect that your `can?` call is the first time Rails tried to load a `MarketAssumption` object in your app, so that's the first time that error occurs.

You can find out more about setting up associations in [the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations).

Comment: Gah! It's hot and it's last thing on a Friday afternoon and I'm an idiot.

Thanks!

Comment: Easy mistake to make. :) Glad you got it sorted.